# Order saving error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry for key 'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID'

Tags: magento-1.9

No changes, updates, or upgrades of any sort in the last few months to the system, Magento 1.9.2.2

Order saving error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '100084489' for key 'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID', query was: INSERT INTO `sales_flat_order` (`coupon_code`, `protect_code`, `shipping_description`, `is_virtual`, `store_id`, `customer_id`, `base_discount_amount`, `base_grand_total`, `base_shipping_amount`, `base_shipping_tax_amount`, `base_subtotal`, `base_tax_amount`, `base_to_global_rate`, `base_to_order_rate`, `discount_amount`, `grand_total`, `shipping_amount`, `shipping_tax_amount`, `store_to_base_rate`, `store_to_order_rate`, `subtotal`, `tax_amount`, `total_qty_ordered`, `customer_is_guest`, `customer_note_notify`, `customer_group_id`, `gift_message_id`, `quote_id`, `base_shipping_discount_amount`, `base_subtotal_incl_tax`, `shipping_discount_amount`, `subtotal_incl_tax`, `weight`, `customer_dob`, `increment_id`, `applied_rule_ids`, `base_currency_code`, `customer_email`, `customer_firstname`, `customer_lastname`, `customer_middlename`, `customer_prefix`, `customer_suffix`, `customer_taxvat`, `discount_description`, `global_currency_code`, `order_currency_code`, `remote_ip`, `shipping_method`, `store_currency_code`, `store_name`, `x_forwarded_for`, `customer_note`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `total_item_count`, `customer_gender`, `hidden_tax_amount`, `base_hidden_tax_amount`, `shipping_hidden_tax_amount`, `base_shipping_hidden_tax_amnt`, `shipping_incl_tax`, `base_shipping_incl_tax`, `auctaneapi_discounts`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, '2018-12-19 16:55:40', '2018-12-19 16:55:40', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Went to database to eav_entity_store, tried increasing order ID by 1, invoice ID, etc - multiple times - no luck. Any other ideas?

Comment: PS. It works after several attempts, and order goes through. Each time I try, the ID does increase, but error still shows

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the cause, but I have seen this error when Magento is attempting to save an order that has reserved an increment ID that is associated with a previous order.

The solution is to search the sales_flat_quote table for a row with reserved_order_id matching the duplicate entry. Setting reserved_order_id to NULL for this row allows the order to be saved using the next available increment ID.

Not a solution, but an answer.